# Splitting a string, reversing then joining the string in python

Tags: python, function, join, reverse, split

I want to Split a string, reverse it and join it back with an X instead of a space in a function.

eg.

'WHO WATCHES THE WATCHERS -> to -> SEHCTAWXOHWXSREHCTAWXEHT'

```
str = ("WHO WATCHES THE WATCHERS")
str = str.split(' ',4)
str.reverse()
print str

str = 'X'
seq = ("who", "watches", "the", "watchers")
print str.join(seq)
```

But that only gets me:

**['WATCHERS', 'THE', 'WATCHES', 'WHO']**

**whoXwatchesXtheXwatchers**

when I want **"SEHCTAWXOHWXSREHCTAWXEHT"**

Please reply in simple function code. I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: You are reusing the name `str` and smashing the old values. Take a look at your code carefully. It's a bad variable name anyway as you mask the built-in `str()` function.

Comment: This seems to be a popular question :=)

Comment: Wait, how do you get "SEHCTAWXOHWXSREHCTAWXEHT" from "WHO WATCHES THE WATCHERS"? Wouldn't the expected output be "SREHCTAWXEHTXSEHCTAWXOHW"?

Comment: It's worth noting there is no need to put brackets around your string literals.

Comment: @Lattyware Yep I totally agree, it was just a quick thing but I have since changed in my code. Thanks

Comment: @NedDeily True, but I was after something a bit more simple. I was confused on that answer

Comment: @Emily Okay that is because (I think) I have to split the 2 words between "WHO WATCHES" and "THE WATCHERS" and then join them back up the other way around. Does that make sense? How would I do that?

Comment: Ah, you should edit your question to say that then. It also appears to be an exact duplicate of the question @NedDeily linked.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is reversing the order of the words, but not the actual words themselves. Try this:

```
def reverse_and_join(s):
  return "X".join(s[::-1].split(" "))
```

This code reverses the entire string, splits it by spaces, and then joins the reversed list of reversed words with "X". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) for an explanation of the `[::-1]` syntax.

Comment: You can simplify this by just reversing earlier. `"X".join(string[::-1].split())`

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I were to put this in a function, would I say 
def a(words,blocksize)
    words = [word[::-1] for word in str.split(" ")]
    words.reverse()
    return "X".join(words)

Comment: I edited the answer to be a function that does this reverse-then-join thing to its argument and returns the result. I'm not sure what `blocksize` is supposed to be.

Comment: Except as mentioned earlier I have to split the 2 words between "WHO WATCHES" and "THE WATCHERS" and then join them back up the other way around as well. Does that make sense? How would I do that?

Comment: @Emily Why use 2 function - split and join - when replace will do the job?

Comment: @Lattyware It varies, So it could be the 3 word in the string, or it could be at the 5th word in the string. Test case would be >>> reverse_and_join('BIG BROTHER IS WATCHING', 1) # Test 1
'GIBXREHTORBXSIXGNIHCTAW' or it could be >>> reverse_and_join('BIG BROTHER IS WATCHING', 2) # Test 2
'SIXGNIHCTAWXREHTORBXGIB'

Comment: So the point at which to split is passed as an argument? You did not make that clear.

Comment: @Lattyware also could you please edit that last comment you made and remove the ATmyname. Thanks

Comment: @Lattyware I dont like having my name plastered all of the internet is all. I wasn't aware when I used my name to join that it would show in comments.

Comment: @Lattyware Yeah I have done that now, hence the "lowlyf" But the one you mentioned me in earlier hasnt updated. Would you be kind enough to change it to lowlyf please? :) thank you.